# Pokemon Go login issue 2 accounts

Tags: pokemon-go

my daughter and I both use my phone to play Pokemon Go. Everything was great until this morning. She literally played all day yesterday and was excited about her progress. After playing, she logs out, that way I don't "mess anything up on her account!". 
Her brother and her went out this morning, and she came back in upset. When she logs in under Google with her email address, it takes her to the setup screen now instead of her in progress trainer account. I can log in just fine to mine, but hers appears to have been reset and all of her progress gone?

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can restore what she had done? The info has to be there somewhere right? At this point I don't recall if we made her separate account through her Google email or through the trainer club, because I haven't logged into mine since first downloading it the first couple of days, so when we clicked on the icon it would always go right into her account. But since she logged out last night it seems to be messed up.

Any help would be appreciated, she is very upset!!

Comment: Are you sure she logged in with the right account? She might have a trainer account and logged in with google, which would explain this situation.

Comment: The servers have been having problems lately. It's possible that she tried when they weren't working, and that's why it won't let her log in.

Comment: She tried both ways. If she tries to login via her email address it takes her to the setup with professor willow and all of her stuff is reset. If she tries with the trainer club it says her user name or password is wrong. The site for forgot user name or password is down

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I think the issue is with the PTC login. Problem now is she doesn't remember her user name fur PTC. She knows her trainer name, but that's not her PTC user name. The PTC site is down so she can't retrieve her user name at the moment.